# Unable to establish SSL connection upon wget on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, ssl, bioinformatics

I use browserSetup.sh to install ucsc Genome Browser in the Cloud (GBiC) program, and getting the error

```
--2021-08-26 13:43:10--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulfitz/mysql-connector-c/master/include/my_config.h
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.109.133, 185.199.110.133, 185.199.108.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.109.133|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I checked this script, there may be an error in this line

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulfitz/mysql-connector-c/master/include/my_config.h -P /usr/include/mysql/
```

I ran this line of code and got the same error，So i want to understand why Unable to establish SSL connection when I use wget.
I ping raw.githubusercontent.com and return

```
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-109-133.github.com (185.199.109.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=87.8 ms
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-109-133.github.com (185.199.109.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=57.9 ms
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-109-133.github.com (185.199.109.133): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=57.9 ms
```

And I tried to use the --no-check-certificate parameter but still can't solve the error，How do i need to solve this problem?

Comment: There might be a deep packet inspection firewall on the way blocking the traffic. Simple packets (ping, TCP handshake) pass through this but once payload is send (TLS handshake) the firewalls decides to block it. This might be done by some middlebox in the network but also by some antivirus product on the local system.